# How do I run jenkins as a single master agent with a docker pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run a single node Jenkins with:

- Jenkins master as a docker container
- Jenkins jobs running in the same container (single node)
- Jenkins docker pipeline tasks, e.g. https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/

I am using the jenkins/jenkins:lts image. The issues I found and resolved so far were:

1. Missing docker binary (added it either via extending the image or bind-mounting)
2. Missing docker plugin not part of the standard recommended plugins (added via the dashboard)

It is able to run docker, but I still get the "Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container", and the script will not execute.

The failure logs are here:

```
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -w "/var/jenkins_home/jobs/Test  Pipeline/branches/master/workspace" -v "/var/jenkins_home/jobs/Test Pipeline/branches/master/workspace:/var/jenkins_home/jobs/Test Pipeline/branches/master/workspace:rw,z" -v "/var/jenkins_home/jobs/Test Pipeline/branches/master/workspace@tmp:/var/jenkins_home/jobs/Test Pipeline/branches/master/workspace@tmp:rw,z" -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** --entrypoint cat node:6.3
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (build)
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
sh: 1: cannot create /var/jenkins_home/jobs/Test Pipeline/branches/master/workspace@tmp/durable-3f202d99/jenkins-log.txt: Directory nonexistent
sh: 1: cannot create /var/jenkins_home/jobs/Test Pipeline/branches/master/workspace@tmp/durable-3f202d99/jenkins-result.txt: Directory nonexistent
```

Why does it not believe it is running in a container? Is it trying to run the agent worker locally and failing?

Comment: check your mount paths and make sure that directory exist

Comment: What do you mean by "check your mount paths"? They exist inside the container. Where else would you want to look?